# Attemp to invoque virtual method 'int.java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null reference object reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I was developing an React Native App where I try to implement Firebase Google Authentication.

My problem comes when I invoke the onClick() funtion of the GoogleSignInButton component of my App which raise the following error:

```
Attem to invoke virtual method 'int.java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null reference object.
getCredencialForProvider
RNFirebaseAuth.java
signInWithCredencial
RNFirebaseAuth
```

The code of my login Screen where I invoke the onCLick method is the following:

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Platform,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Keyboard,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import {Background} from '../components/Background';
import {WhiteLogo} from '../components/WhiteLogo';
import {loginStyles} from '../theme/loginTheme';
import {useForm} from '../hooks/useForm';
import {StackScreenProps} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {AuthContext} from '../context/AuthContext';
import {signInUser} from '../api/AuthApi';
import {GoogleSignin, GoogleSigninButton} from 'react-native-google-signin';
import {Providers} from '../config/firebase';

interface Props extends StackScreenProps<any, any> {}

export const LoginScreen = ({navigation}: Props) => {
  const {signIn, errorMessage, removeError} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const {Firebase} = require('../config/firebase');
  const {email, password, onChange} = useForm({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });
  GoogleSignin.configure({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'],
    webClientId: Providers.google.PROVIDER_ID,
    offlineAccess: true,
    forceConsentPrompt: true,
    accountName: Providers.google.PROVIDER_ID,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    if (errorMessage.length === 0) return;

    Alert.alert('Login incorrecto', errorMessage, [
      {
        text: 'Ok',
        onPress: removeError,
      },
    ]);
  }, [errorMessage]);

  const onLogin = () => {
    console.log({email, password});
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    signIn({correo: email, password});
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* Background */}
      <Background />

      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={{flex: 1}}
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}>
        <View style={loginStyles.formContainer}>
          {/* Keyboard avoid view */}
          <WhiteLogo />

          <Text style={loginStyles.title}>Login</Text>

          <Text style={loginStyles.label}>Email:</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Ingrese su email:"
            placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.4)"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            underlineColorAndroid="white"
            style={[
              loginStyles.inputField,
              Platform.OS === 'ios' && loginStyles.inputFieldIOS,
            ]}
            selectionColor="white"
            onChangeText={value => onChange(value, 'email')}
            value={email}
            onSubmitEditing={onLogin}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
          />

          <Text style={loginStyles.label}>Contraseña:</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="******"
            placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.4)"
            underlineColorAndroid="white"
            secureTextEntry
            style={[
              loginStyles.inputField,
              Platform.OS === 'ios' && loginStyles.inputFieldIOS,
            ]}
            selectionColor="white"
            onChangeText={value => onChange(value, 'password')}
            value={password}
            onSubmitEditing={onLogin}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
          />

          {/* Boton login */}
          <View style={loginStyles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.8}
              style={loginStyles.button}
              onPress={() => signInUser}>
              <Text style={loginStyles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          {/* Crear una nueva cuenta */}
          <View style={loginStyles.newUserContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.8}
              onPress={() => navigation.replace('RegisterScreen')}>
              <Text style={loginStyles.buttonText}>Nueva cuenta </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={loginStyles.googleButtonConteiner}>
            <GoogleSigninButton
              style={loginStyles.googleButton}
              size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
              color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
              onPress={() =>
                Firebase.auth()!
                  .signInWithCredential(Providers.google.credential)
                  .then(() => navigation.navigate('ProtectedScreen'))
              }
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </>
  );
};
```

my package.json configuration is the next:

```
{
  "name": "productos-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.7.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.7.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "firebase": "^9.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-google-button": "^0.7.2",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.18.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/firebase": "^3.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.64.13",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.2",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

And in the case that it can be related with the permission on the manifest, here it's my AndroidMaifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.productosapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I hope you can guess where the solution comes, and if it's like this take thanks in advance!

Comment: How is your `Providers.google.credential` initialized?

Comment: I don't guess so. How I should initialized  the credencials??

Comment: https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth#google?